# Вывод данных словаря в компонент (React)

Tags: reactjs

Есть массив:

```
let data = [
    { "kat": "1", "fio": "Цех наладки", "tel": "2-00-01" },
    { "kat": "1", "fio": "Цех наладки", "tel": "2-00-02" },
    { "kat": "1", "fio": "Мастер участка", "tel": "3-00-01" },
    { "kat": "1", "fio": "Мастер участка", "tel": "3-00-02" },
];
```

Вот так я его группирую:

```
const res = JSON.stringify(
    data.reduce((r, a) => {
        r[a.fio] = r[a.fio] || [];
        r[a.fio].push({tel: a.tel, kat: a.kat});
        return r;
    }, {}), true, 4
)
```

Итог:

```
{
    "Цех наладки": [
        {
            "tel": "2-00-01",
            "kat": "1"
        },
        {
            "tel": "2-00-02",
            "kat": "1"
        }
    ],
    "Мастер участка": [
        {
            "tel": "3-00-01",
            "kat": "1"
        },
        {
            "tel": "3-00-02",
            "kat": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**Вопрос**:
Как правильно перебрать объект, чтобы вывести данные в компонент по образцу ниже?
Или (как я мне кажется) я изначально не правильно "собираю" const res?

```
Мастер участка
--------------
тел: 3-00-01
тел: 3-00-02


Цех наладки
--------------
2-00-01
2-00-01
```

Comment: 1. А зачем вы его в строку сериализуете? 2. Если сгруппировали, то в чем проблема то?

Comment: Проблема: не могу понять, как прогонять через цикл данный объект. Т.е., как взять поле "fio" (которое в готовом результате разное) и через него "перебрать" массив (tel, kat).

Answer (score 1):

Сначала надо получить массив ключей объекта
[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Потом перебрать этот массив, получая нужное значение по ключу

```
res[key]
```

```js
let data = [
    { "kat": "1", "fio": "Цех наладки", "tel": "2-00-01" },
    { "kat": "1", "fio": "Цех наладки", "tel": "2-00-02" },
    { "kat": "1", "fio": "Мастер участка", "tel": "3-00-01" },
    { "kat": "1", "fio": "Мастер участка", "tel": "3-00-02" },
];

const res = data.reduce((r, a) => {
    r[a.fio] = r[a.fio] || [];
    r[a.fio].push({tel: a.tel, kat: a.kat});
    return r;
}, {});

Object.keys(res).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(key);
  console.log(res[key]);
});
```